# How to add README.md on github but not have same README.md in home directory while using a bare git repository for managing dotfiles?

Tags: git, github, dotfiles, readme, git-repo

I manage my dotfiles using git in a bare repository.  See [article by Harfang Perch](https://harfangk.github.io/2016/09/18/manage-dotfiles-with-a-git-bare-repository.html) for details on this method.

It works great but I'd like to add a README.md to the root of the [repository on github](https://github.com/makeyourownmaker/dotfiles).

How do I add a README.md to the github repository root directory but **not** have that file show up in my home directories?

If I push a README.md to github then delete the README.md in my home directory this will result in

```
deleted:    README.md
```

messages from `git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ --work-tree=$HOME status` which I'd prefer to avoid.

As far as I'm aware github only renders README and README.md files in the repository root (and sub-directories but that's not relevant for this question).

I haven't seen other github dotfile bare repositories with README.md files but I've only checked 5.

Github wiki pages don't solve this problem unless there is some magic to display them in the root of the repository using a hidden .dotfile.  Perhaps I'm grasping at straws but, is there any way to link and display a gist in the repository root directory on github?

I don't currently use gitlab but moving to gitlab, or a similar git hosting service, is a possibility if they have support for this that github does not.

Comment: I would recommend not using a bare repository here. Keep the repository in a single `.dotfiles` directory, and create symlinks like `$HOME/.bashrc -> $HOME/.dotfiles/.bashrc` as needed. You can write a script to create all the necessary symlinks and store that in the repository as well.

Comment: (Many, though not all, programs may also look in a standard location like `~/.config` for configuration files, which means you can simply clone your `.dotfiles` as `.config` instead. Such programs will probably honor a standard environment variable that specifies which directory contains the configuration, meaning the only file you need in `~` directly is the shell configuration file sets that environment variable.)

Comment: @chepner I chose the bare repository dotfiles management approach to **avoid** using symlinks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can put your README file in a .github folder and it will be automatically detected on github to be displayed on your repo main view

Comment: That works :-) Thank you ever so much for your answer! FWIW what you describe is documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-readmes)

Answer (score 3):

The `Readme.md` displayed by default on GitHub is the one in the `master` branch.

You could create a `home` branch that wouldn't have the Readme, and use that branch as a work branch.

You would probably want to merge to master on a regular basis, you could add one or two convenient aliases to do this in one go, either when committing or when pushing.

---

You could try to get clever with subtrees too.

Answer (score 2):

Although not ideal, one simple solution is to put your README and any other meta-files about your configuration into a tracked `.dotfiles` directory. You can then link to the README file in your repo's about section on GitHub.

An example of this setup: https://github.com/anandpiyer/.dotfiles

Upon trying this myself, I realized my repo itself is stored in a `.dotfiles` directory so the README gets mixed in with the internal Git files. However, placing it in `~/.dotfiles/README.md` and adding/pushing worked as expected. You could try a different directory name like `.about` if you don't want it mixed in.

Comment: `README.md` is located on `.dotfiles` folder of your repo. Is this `README.md` is commom for every branch ?. Because in my configs actually I need to manage different branches which contains different themes so I would like to add screenshots to that `README` which shows in every branch. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you would need to pull the latest README into each branch to have it shared like you're describing, maybe a script could help automate this.

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks. I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can do for now is to link to a gist from the About section.

The About section is displayed on the right-hand side of github repository pages.

Comment: Here is an example I found that uses the about section to link to a README in a .dotfiles folder so it stays self-contained. https://github.com/anandpiyer/.dotfiles

Comment: That is preferable to the link I have in the About section to a separate gist.  Consider adding it as an answer.  Well spotted example!

Comment: Added as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63057672/8371763)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation here for `README.md` https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-readmes

> If you put your README file in your repository's hidden .github, root,
> or docs directory, GitHub will recognize and automatically surface
> your README to repository visitors.
>
> If a repository contains more than one README file, then the file
> shown is chosen from locations in the following order: the .github
> directory, then the repository's root directory, and finally the docs
> directory.

So `.github`, `/` and `docs/`

Comment: I know this post is old– but this answer is clearer on all the different directories you could display README.

Answer (score -4):

commit and push the correct **readme** file to your repository,

add the **readme** file in your **.gitignore** file and now u can change the readme file in your computer and commit your changes without any problem.

if git not ignore the readme file, try:

**commit all your changes** and run

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

for reset the followed files on git

Comment: Adding a tracked file to `.gitignore` doesn't make sense — `.gitignore` ignores only **untracked** files.

Comment: `git rm -r --cached .` This advice is even worse, it deletes everything from the repo so the OP would loose all his files.